I am unable to interact with the element that opens on another page
`When I click on the Treasury button, Cypress calls another page that is opened outside the execution environment. If I don't use visit I can't interact with the element. I don't want to use visit, if I just use .invoke('removeAttr', 'target') without visit, cyprees doesn't work.
See my code and web code please.
import 'cypress-iframe';

describe('Access TES', () => {
  before(() => {
    //
    cy.visit('https://multiportal-hml.paycashprotege.com.br/portal2PN/faces/faces1/index.jsp');

    // 
    cy.get('input#frmcaindex\\:NOME_USUARIO', { timeout: 10000 })
      .should('be.visible')
      .type('luirenba')
      .should('have.value', 'xxxxx');

    // 
    cy.get('input#frmcaindex\\:SENHA_ATUAL', { timeout: 10000 })
      .should('be.visible')
      .type('xxxxxx')
      .should('have.value', 'xxxxxxx');

    // 
    cy.get('#frmcaindex\\:btnOk', { timeout: 10000 })
      .should('be.visible')
      .click();
  });

  it('click button [12 Tesouraria]', () => {
    // Clica no botão [12 Tesouraria] após rolar para ele e garantir que está visível
    cy.get('a.aht-controle-TS_10315')
      .scrollIntoView()
      .should('be.visible')
      .invoke('removeAttr', 'target') 
      .click();

    //the new page is being loaded twice, after clicking this button and visiting it. If I use click I don't access the page elements
    cy.wait(10000);

    // If I remove the visit I cannot interact with the element
    cy.visit('https://multiportal-hml2.paycashprotege.com.br/portal2TS/faces/ts_sistemas.jsp');

    // 
    cy.frameLoaded('frame[name="main"]');

    // 
    cy.iframe('frame[name="main"]')
      .find('input[type="image"][name="page:frmSideMenu:_id42"]')
      .scrollIntoView()
      .should('be.visible')
      .click();
  });
});

Web Code
<html>
<head>
    <title>ts_sistemas</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE">
    <script language="JavaScript">
    var Popup = new function() {
        this.openedWindows = {};
        this.open = function(url, name, specs, replace) {
            var handle = window.open(url, name, specs, replace);
            this.openedWindows[name] = handle;
            return handle;
        };
        this.close = function(instanceName) {
            if(this.openedWindows[instanceName])
                this.openedWindows[instanceName].close();
        };
        this.closeAll = function() {
            for(var dialog in this.openedWindows)
                this.openedWindows[dialog].close();
        };
    };

    function inicio() {
        window.moveTo(0, 0);
        window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
    }
    function fim() {
        var simbSistema = "ts";
        var nome = (window.name==(simbSistema+"logout")) ? (simbSistema+"ctrl") : (simbSistema+"logout");
        var paginaLogout = window.open("/portal2TS/faces/"+simbSistema+"logout.jsp", nome, "resizable=yes,menubar=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,status=yes,width=1004,height=677,top=0,left=0");
        paginaLogout.focus();
        window.close();
        Popup.closeAll();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<frameset frameborder="0" rows="1px,*" framespacing="0" onbeforeunload="fim()" onload="inicio()">
    <frame src="/portal2TS/blank.jsp" scrolling="no">
    <frame name="main" width="100%" src="/portal2TS/faces/tssistemas.jsp" scrolling="no">
</frameset>
</html>


Why don't you want to use visit?

ts_sistemas.jsp seems to be be source code, you would need the user-facing URL.

<frameset><frame></frameset>is not <iframe>, you cannot use cypress-iframe to access the <frame> elements.
See HTML.COM - Frames for documentation on the differences.
This is roughly how you access the <frame>
cy.get('frame[name="main"]')
  .then($frame => $frame[0].contentWindow)  
  .its('document.body')                      
  .within(() => {            

    // Query HTML inside the <frame>

    cy.get('input[type="image"][name="page:frmSideMenu:_id42"]')
      .scrollIntoView()
      .should('be.visible')
      .click();
  })

The page code is Java-in-HTML (.jsp) so the content of the frame might be loading from remote (asynchronously), in which case you would need some assertions in the frame part of the code to make sure contentWindow and it's document.body are as expected (i.e loaded).
I can't tell exactly what those assertions would be, as the page does not work here, but you will be able to work it out by logging document.body to the console.
